# When to link against appcompat and constraint-layout support libraries and when not

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm migrating my Android NDK project from Ant/ndk-build to Gradle/CMake. Previously, I was using the Android SDK and NDK from summer 2012, now I've updated to the latest versions. I build using the command line, not from Android Studio.

As a basis for the migration I've had a look at the HelloJNI NDK sample. Its `build.gradle` contains these two dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
}
```

I've done some research on the Android support library and I think I don't need it for my project because I'm targetting Android 9 and my app doesn't need any newer features so I don't think I need to link the support library.

However, the HelloJNI example is confusing me here because it includes the v7 appcompat library but at the same time its `build.gradle` says that the project needs at least v23:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.hellojni'
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang'
        }
    }
}
```

So isn't it superfluous in this case to link against the appcompat v7 when the project itself requires v23? It doesn't make sense to me but maybe I'm not understanding everything correctly here, so that's why I'd like to ask.

The second thing I'm not sure about is linking against constraint layout. HelloJNI does this as well but I don't know why. From my research it looks like constraint layout allows apps to do some advanced layout tricks but of course HelloJNI doesn't do that... so why does it still link against constraint layout?

To conclude, as far as I understand, I don't need to link against appcompat v7 because my app targets v9 and doesn't use any newer features and I also don't need to link against constraint layout because my app doesn't need the functionality provided by the constraint layout library either. The only thing that is confusing me here is why the HelloJNI sample links against both libraries when I think that shouldn't be necessary for such a primitive example. So is that maybe just a matter of convention rather than of necessity?

Thanks to anybody who can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So isn't it superfluous in this case to link against the appcompat v7 when the project itself requires v23?

With a `minSdkVersion` of 23, you do not need `appcompat-v7`, but you will then need to not use anything from it (e.g., `AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`).

Google likes everyone to use `appcompat-v7`, but it adds ~1MB of bloat to your app for little added value, particularly with a `minSdkVersion` of 23.

> The second thing I'm not sure about is linking against constraint layout. HelloJNI does this as well but I don't know why.

Google has converted many of their templates and examples over to use `ConstraintLayout`.

> From my research it looks like constraint layout allows apps to do some advanced layout tricks but of course HelloJNI doesn't do that... so why does it still link against constraint layout?

Because they are using `ConstraintLayout` in [a layout resource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-jni/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_hello_jni.xml)... that itself is unused. If I had to guess, they copied their JNI code into a new project created by a template that added the layout resource, dependency upon the `constraint` artifact, dependency upon `appcompat-v7`, etc.

> I don't need to link against appcompat v7 because my app targets v9

<strike>Your app has `targetSdkVersion` of 25, not 9.</strike>

Comment: Thanks! But: "Your app has targetSdkVersion of 25, not 9." Read my original post again. The snippet is from HelloJNI, not from my project. In my project both `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are 9.

Comment: @Andreas: OK, sorry about that. You may find it difficult to do modern app development with such low values. Of note, you should consider avoiding any `com.android.support` libraries, as they will require `minSdkVersion` of 14 starting with the 26.x.y version of those artifacts. You could use `com.android.support` libraries and just plan on sticking with `25.x.y` versions, but you are unlikely to get any bug fixes to those libraries after mid-2017.